# How to do this PHP loop in a table

Tags: php, html, dom

I use simple-php-dom to get some html from other website.
Then I use foreach to find 3 things : business name, address and phone.
Finally I want to print those 3 info in my table using php loop.

Question : How to write the loop inside the table ?

Here's my PHP code to get the 3 info from other site :

```html
<?php  
//Get Biz Name
foreach($html->find('a[class=biz-name js-analytics-click]') as $biz_name_root){
  foreach ($biz_name_root->find('span') as $biz_name) {
    echo $biz_name->plaintext . "<br>";
  }
}

//Get Address
foreach($html->find('address') as $address){
  echo $address . '<br>';
}

// Get Phone
foreach($html->find('span[class=biz-phone]') as $phone){
  echo $phone . '<br>';
}
?>
```

Here's the table that I want to store those 3 information to :
I want to store the `$biz_name->plaintext` to `<td>biz_name</td>`, the `$address` to
`<td>address</td>` and `$phone` to `<td>phone</td>`field.

```html
<table class="table">
  <thead class="thead-dark">
    <tr>
      <th scope="col">No</th>
      <th scope="col">Biz Name</th>
      <th scope="col">Address</th>
      <th scope="col">Phone</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
  <?php 
  for ($i=1; $i < count($html->find('address'))+2  ; $i++) { ?>
    <tr>
      <th scope="row"><?php echo $i ?></th>
      <td>biz_name</td>
      <td>address</td>
      <td>phone</td>
    </tr>
    <?php }
    ?>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Answer (score 0):

You should store all found info in arrays to iterate through them:

```
<?php  
//Get Biz Name
$bisNames = array();
foreach($html->find('a[class=biz-name js-analytics-click]') as $biz_name_root){
  foreach ($biz_name_root->find('span') as $biz_name) {
    $bizNames[] = $biz_name->plaintext;
  }
}

//Get Address
$adresses = array();
foreach($html->find('address') as $address){
  $adresses[] = $address;
}

// Get Phone
$phones = array();
foreach($html->find('span[class=biz-phone]') as $phone){
  $phones[] = $phone;
}
?>
```

And then:

```
<table class="table">
  <thead class="thead-dark">
    <tr>
      <th scope="col">No</th>
      <th scope="col">Biz Name</th>
      <th scope="col">Address</th>
      <th scope="col">Phone</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
  <?php 
  for ($i=1; $i < count($html->find('address'))+2  ; $i++) { ?>
    <tr>
      <th scope="row"><?php echo $i ?></th>
      <td><?php echo $bizNames[$i]; ?></td>
      <td><?php echo $adresses[$i]; ?></td>
      <td><?php echo $phones[$i]; ?></td>
    </tr>
    <?php }
    ?>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: When I store to array `$addresses[] = $address;` then do `print_r($addresses)`, I got 0 for all the index of the array. `Array ( [0] =>address1,  [0] =>address2,  [0] =>address3` .... So it won't work when I loop using for on the table. Any advice ?

Comment: What are the values of `$phones` and `$bizNames`? Are they as you expected or also zeros? Try making `var_dump($html->find('address'))` to see what is returned.